# Obtaining a table by the item type in LINQ to SQL

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

How can you make something like this generic

```
return from items in _db.Table
    select items;
```

I would like to do something like this

```
public class Data<T> ( where T is the model object )
```

so the Table will change to the value of T

How would this look as a generic class with a save method for instance

Thanks

Comment: How would DataRepository<T> be able to fill GetTable<T>?

Answer (score 4):

In LINQ-to-SQL, the data-context has [`GetTable<T>()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb357220.aspx):

```
var table = _db.GetTable<T>();
etc
```

Comment: var table = _db.GetTable<T>;
Error 1 Cannot assign method group to an implicitly-typed local variable

Answer (score 1):

Adding to Marc Gravell's answer, you could have a generic update method that looks like this:

```
public void Update(TEntity entity, TEntity original)
{
    using (DataContext context = CreateContext())
    {
        Table<TEntity> table = context.GetTable<TEntity>();

        table.Attach(entity, original);
        context.SubmitChanges();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
... _db.GetTable<MyType> ...
```